# no response from server: unknown: transportError

Tags: swift, mongodb-stitch

I am getting the following error when querying my stitch remote collection in Swift: `no response from server: unknown: transportError`

This is my test query:

```
//var aircraftCollection: RemoteMongoCollection<Aircraft>!
var aircraftCollection: RemoteMongoCollection<Document>!

var mongoDb = MongoDB()

class MongoDB: ErrorListener {
    init() {
        do {
            let client = try Stitch
                .initializeDefaultAppClient(withClientAppID: "....")

            let mongoClient = try client.serviceClient(
                fromFactory: remoteMongoClientFactory, withName: "...."
            )

            client.auth.login(withCredential: UserPasswordCredential(withUsername: "....", withPassword: "....")) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let user):
                    // Get collections from database
                    aircraftCollection = mongoClient.db("database").collection("aircraft")

                    let aircraft = Document(dictionaryLiteral: ("_id", ObjectId()))
                    aircraftCollection.sync.insertOne(document: aircraft, { (result) in
                        switch result {
                        case .success(_):
                            print("inserted successfully")
                        case .failure(let e):
                            fatalError(e.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    })

                    aircraftCollection.find().first { result in
                        switch result {
                        case .success(let aircraft):
                            let aircraftList = aircraft.map { $0 }
                            print(aircraftList)
                        case .failure(let error):
                            // this is where error occurs
                            print(error.localizedDescription) 
                        }
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error in login: \(error)")
                }
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("do catch error")
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

My connection seems to be fine, I have another stitch app built in JavaScript on localhost that performs the same query without any trouble.
I am using `pod 'StitchSDK', '~> 5.0.0'`

Answer (score -1):

This shouldn't matter, but are you intentionally trying to utilize mobile sync, or would you rather just call aircraftCollection.insertOne()